# Date Picker for Bootstrap 4 or Material components

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-components-web

I am now looking for a date picker for either Bootstrap 4 or Material components.

It would be great if it:

1. is visually consistent with the design system (I have found pickers with bootstrap 3 and pickers offered by mdb, but they do not look good within the app),
2. is available through npm and usable with react,
3. supports date range selection.

Does anybody know some components or libraries like this? Thank you so much!

Comment: https://flatpickr.js.org/ https://github.com/haoxins/react-flatpickr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:-
`https://github.com/Pikaday/Pikaday` 
*demo* `https://pikaday.com/`
its built with vanilla js and can be used with any library that's the cool thing about it and you have alot of options to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this , I am also using this Jquery library.

Firstly add these path inn your file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"> 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
    <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {

   var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
   var end = moment();

   function cb(start, end) {
     $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + 
       end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
   }

  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
       'Today': [moment(), moment()],
       'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  }, cb);

  cb(start, end);

 });
</script>
```